# Adding to scala map within for loop and conditional statement

Tags: scala

I'm getting an error message of "error: type arguments [Any] do not conform to trait Cloneable's type parameter bounds [+A <: AnyRef]," which I can't make heads or tails of.

Specifically,

```
var M = mutable.Map[Int, mutable.Set[Int]]()
for(i <- 1 to 100; j <- 1 to 100) {
    if(!M.contains(i)) {M += i -> mutable.Set[Int](j)}
    else {M(i) += j} 
}
```

(I'm actually trying something more complicated, but this is the error generating code tweaked and simplified to a minimum)

And the last line of the above code generates the error message. If I strip it down further

```
for(i <- 1 to 100; j <- 1 to 100) {
    if(!M.contains(i)) {M += i -> mutable.Set[Int](j)}
}
```

it works!

How do I make the above code work?

Comment: As a side note, `M += i -> (M.getOrElse(i, mutable.Set[Int]()) + j)` would be a slightly more idiomatic way to write the body of the loop.

Comment: @Travis Thanks! That's the solution I was looking for. If you convert your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to select it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the answers below probably do a better job of addressing the question as posed?

Answer (score 7):

Digal diagnosed the problem (failure to unify the types of the if-else branches) and it looks like a compiler bug. Here's a further simplified case that will give an error in the REPL, after a lengthy compilation time,

```
if (true) {
  null: collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]
} else {
  null: collection.mutable.Set[Int]
}
```

In the meantime, you can get your code to compile with an explicit type sprinkled somewhere in the if-else statement,

```
for(i <- 1 to 100; j <- 1 to 100) {
  if(!M.contains(i)) {M += i -> mutable.Set[Int](j)}
  else {M(i) += j}: Unit 
}
```

I filed an issue here: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4938

Comment: Wow! I've never been the discoverer of a bona fide bug in an established compiler before.

Answer (score 6):

I've reduced your example even further:

```
scala> if(!M.contains(1)) {M += 1 -> mutable.Set[Int](1)} else {M(1) += 1}; 
<console>:9: error: type arguments [Any] do not conform to trait Cloneable's type parameter bounds [+A <: AnyRef]
val res17 =
    ^
```

The problem seem to occur when compiler tries to find common return type for both branches:
The first one is

```
scala> M += 1 -> mutable.Set[Int](1)
res19: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]] = ...
```

And the "else" part is

```
scala> M(1) += 1
res18: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1)
```

If I add a return value to the end of this expression, REPL eats it without errors:

```
scala> if(!M.contains(1)) {M += 1 -> mutable.Set[Int](1)} else {M(1) += 1}; println("hello")
hello
```

Because the expression's return type is Unit.

Comment: Thanks! I now understand the error message. But the work around is too clunky. I'm sure there's a more suave, orthodox way to do this.